How do I make await function last less than one millisecond?
I am currently making a sorting algorithm visualizer using HTML, CSS, and JS. I have most of it down, but I want to give it the ability to sort faster than one comparison a millisecond.
Here is my code:
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sorting Algorithm Visualizer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="algorithm">
            <option value="bubble">Bubble Sort</option>
            <option value="selection">Selection Sort</option>
            <option value="insertion">Insertion Sort</option>
            </select>
        <input type="text" id="Size" value=100>
        <button onclick="gen()">Generate</button>
        <input type="number" id="delay" min="0" value="1"> (ms delay)
    </div>
        <div class="bars" id="setup"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

CSS
.bars{
  background-color: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

JS
var list;
var ind;
var size;
var sort;
var delay;
var count;
const content = document.getElementById("content");
var height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.9);
var width = Math.floor(window.innerWidth);

function swap(arr, a, b) {
  [arr[a], arr[b]] = [arr[b], arr[a]];
  update(a);
  update(b);
}

async function bubbleSort(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (arr.length - i - 1); j++) {
      await sleep(delay);
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        swap(list, j, j + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}

async function selectionSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let lowest = i;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      await sleep(delay);
      if (arr[j] < arr[lowest]) {
        lowest = j;
      }
    }
    if (lowest !== i) {
      swap(list, i, lowest);
    }
  }
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  ind = list.length - 1;
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    swap(arr, i, j);
  }
}

function update(item) {
  const bar = document.getElementById("bar" + item);
  if (bar) {
    bar.style.visibility = "visible";
    bar.style.height = (height / size) * list[item] + "px";
    const hue = (list[item] / size) * 360;
    bar.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
  }
}

function createBars(arr) {
  count = 0;
  while (count < arr.length) {
    var bar = document.createElement('div');
    bar.classList.add("bars");
    bar.setAttribute('id', "bar" + count);
    document.body.appendChild(bar);
    bar.style.width = Math.ceil(width / size) + "px";
    bar.style.visibility = "visible";
    bar.style.bottom = "0%";
    bar.style.left = count * width / size + "px";
    bar.style.height = (height / size) * arr[count] + "px";
    const hue = (arr[count] / size) * 360;
    bar.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
    count++;
    updateAll();
  }
}

async function gen() {
  if (list != undefined) {
    var element = document.getElementById("parent");
    element.textContent = "";
  }
  list = [];
  size = document.getElementById("Size").value;
  for (count = 1; count <= size; count++) {
    list.push(count);
  }
  shuffle(list);
  createBars(list);
  await sleep(1000);
  sort = document.getElementById("algorithm").value;
  delay = document.getElementById("delay").value;
  switch (sort) {
    case "bubble":
      bubbleSort(list);
      break;
    case "selection":
      selectionSort(list);
      break;
  }
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(d => setTimeout(d, milliseconds));
}

function updateAll() {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    update(list, i);
  }
}

What I want is that if the ms delay is set between 0 and 1, comparisons will be made at that speed.
All help is appreciated.

Just put the await inside an if that checks the duration of the delay so that the iterations of the sort don't await anything. Note that since this is for a visualization any delay less than ~15ms is probably pointless, since that's roughly the limit of human perception.

Normally when doing animation with code, you use something called delta time, also for animation in JS, there is the dedicated requestAnimationFrame  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame

here's a little thing I cooked up https://jsfiddle.net/coqem46n/ probably really nasty code, but it works (I also fixed a couple of the bugs in your code)

That's not what await is. Waiting for a specific time is not a case for strictly asynchronous programming. It is for cases where you expect things to happen but can't be 100% sure that they actually happen (error handling ) or when they happen (resolve). Such as calling a Web API where you expect a response but can't be 100% sure that it will receive the response at which time it will be received or get any kind of failure such as 403 or 404.
